# Opening a file through Git Bash using a particular software (For Windows)

Tags: linux, command-line, git, git-bash

I want to open a file through Git Bash command prompt using a particular software then what is the command for it.
Example:- I am in the directory /c/users/user and I want to open a file named text.txt which is already present in the directory using **Atom text editor**.
The command I am using is (after reaching the appropriate directory) **$ start atom text.txt** and
**$ start atom . text.txt** but both of these are not working. (FOR WINDOWS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have either cmd or bash find executables (binaries) you need to have the the PATH variable contain the folder(s) where the executable file(s) can be found.

GNU/Linux, Cygwin, MINGW, Git Bash:

```
$ echo $PATH  # will display current setting, where to look for executables 
$ PATH=$PATH:/home/bin   # add /home/bin  temporarily, 
# add this line to e.g. $HOME/.bashrc to have it set every time you log in.
```

In a similar manner for windows; To set it permanently though you need to run "system" from "control panel" and click on "Environment variables" to find the PATH variable, and there is one that is system wide (for all users) and one for you only.

*Later windows versions e.g. W10 has a hiding cloak for the System settings; i.e. find "Advanced System settings" which will reveal the very same / original dialog from earlier versions.  - that for making things "easier".*

---

The GNU/Linux equivalent of Windows `start` depends on which window manager you run:

```
xdg-open args ...      # generally, but you might need to do
gnome-open args ...    # for GNOME, or
kde-open args ...      # for KDE
```

Create a file named `start` and type, this into it:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdg-open "$*"
```

... then also do...

- place it in e.g. $HOME/bin/ and
- do `chmod 755 $HOME/bin/start`  # set 'exceutable' permissions
- put `$HOME/bin/` in your PATH (as shown above)

Answer (score 1):

Start command will not work in Git Bash, make sure Atom is in the bin directory, and run:

```
$ atom ./text.txt
```

Comment: the whole atom setup in the bin?

Comment: Or if atom is in other directory, use `cd` to navigate there

Comment: i have added atom to bin and typed the same command as mentioned but there is an error message bash: atom: command not found

Comment: if i am going to the directory where atom is present and typing the command $ start atom ./text.txt then that is creating a new file inside the atom's directory and I am unable to edit the one that I intend to.

Answer (score -1):

actually...
the start command does work in Git Bash -- I've used it many times in scripts

Git Bash scripts will also run Windows apps and let you modify file(s) in the directory you specify if:

1. you have the Windows app in your environment PATH
2. you provide the full path and file name to the file (such as /c/mydir/myfile.txt) when you run the command

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1243829)